# Missing attribute name in Visual Studio

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, bootstrap-4

I am working on a project using ASP.NET CORE with MVC and when I want to use bootstrap (i think?) I get this warning, on a video on youtube he could see the B from bootstrap (autofill thing) when he used the div class name... but I don't get it and I see that bootstrap is loaded into my project.. I don't understand I followed the exact same instructions of the guy but mine just don't work.. I am beginner to visual studio and programming so I struggle with it.. thanks in advance..

[image: error]

Comment: it look like  you didn't add  bootstrap cdn

Answer (score 0):

The tag name should be `div`, instead of `div-class`.

```
<div class="row>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks alot.. such a simple thing that got me stuck.. i guess thats why progrmaming its hard haha

Comment: I suggest learning [html](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_basic.asp), before step forward to bootstrap.